# Подключение к бд программно

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

у меня есть база данных .mdf Мне надо после установки указать этот файл в форме. а потом программа должна подключится к этой БД. БД находится в другом компьютере которая подключена к моему локально.

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: *БД находится в другом компьютере которая подключена к моему локально.* Это, пардон, как? MS SQL не станет работать с файлом БД, лежащем на удалённом ресурсе...

Comment: Подробней пожалуйста! Мы не Вангуем

Comment: В общем то ситуация такая: Я хочу написать программу для школьников. В школе в компьютерном классе есть 15 компьютеров. Я хочу написать программу и создаю БД.  БД хранится в компьютере преподавателя. а программа устанавливается в компьютеры учеников. И ученики когда запускает программу из компьютера за которыми сидят, программа должно подключится к базе данных которая находится в компьютере преподавателя. Программу пишу на   windows forms

Comment: Вообще то Ваш вопрос - как подключиться программам на компьютере учеников к MS SQL серверу, установленному на компьютере учителя. Судя по сумбуру в вопросе отвечать Вам бесполезно, пока Вы не прочтете элементарный учебник по MS SQL и работе в C# с базами данных. Это не снобизм, просто чтобы понять, то что Вам скажут, нужно иметь минимальный базовы уровень

Comment: Я знаю базовый уровень. Я уже написал  программу и создал БД. Мне надо только изменить конфигурацию подключения к БД. Этого я не могу сделать. Я хотел конкретного ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же, строка подключения у вас будет другая, это подключение к локальному серверу, укажите имя или ip вашего sql server.

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Owner;User ID=;Password=;");
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Label7.Text = "Connection Open ! ";
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label8.Text = "Can not open connection ! ";
            }
```